# SOLR issue with words containing dash, hypens etc

Tags: php, apache, solr, lucene

for some reason my SOLR installation acts wonky (im also a newbie fo this topic..)

example:
in my DB i have an item named **"Brandname XX-7 Yadda Ladida"**

if i search:

> `Brandname XX7`
>    I don't get the item on the results (first 20) at all
>
> `Brandname XX-7` I get the expected result in 8th position; 
>   first position is taken by item "Brandname XX-2 Yadda Ladida"
>
> `Brandname XX-7 Ladida` I get the expected result in 7th position; 
>   first position is taken by item "Brandname XX-2 Yadda Ladida"
>
> `Brandname XX-7 Yadda Ladida` I get the expected result AGAIN in 7th position; 
>   first position is taken by item "Brandname XX-2 Yadda Ladida"

PS. eveything is case **insensitive**

what am I doing wrong???
please advise..

this is my managed-schema xml file
http://pastebin.com/Z9nc36QD

**UPDATE**
this is an example query searching for "boss dd-7"

```
  "debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"Brandname xx-7",
    "querystring":"Brandname xx-7",
    "parsedquery":"_text_:Brandname (_text_:xx _text_:7)",
    "parsedquery_toString":"_text_:Brandname (_text_:xx _text_:7)",
```

Comment: Not super-familiar with Solr, but I know from experience with Elasticsearch [also based on Lucene] is that strings containing hyphens tend to get tokenized on them. IIRC ES calls them "analyzed fields" and to get around this you have to use `fieldname.raw` instead of `fieldname`. HTH

Comment: You can append `debugQuery` to your query to see how the score is calculated, and the reason is probably because of tokenization (in particular the first query not matching anything). You can use different tokenizers with different fields and different weights to get the matching profile you want, and use debugQuery to see how each weight is applied to the final ranking of the documents.

Comment: Perhaps some of the documents were given a [boost when indexed](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22)?  At any rate, as @MatsLIndh said, a [debugQuery](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#debugQuery) would be the way to debug it.

Comment: it seems like is parsing the query breaking the words in Brand / DD / 7, os basically ig weighing more dd-2 because 2<7... it seems it not considering dd-7 as one word...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, not it works by simply removing this line in my schema

```
<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />
```

and adding

```
             <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
```

my final code (consider my field is text_general)

```
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```